# Can I ask if an algorithm I wrote is a new one (unique) and ask for review / feedback on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Was wondering if I can post details of a sorting algorithm variation I wrote and get feedback on my understanding of it, whether its really unique and so on.

If not, is it possible to suggest a place for me to do so?

I have already seen a similar question posted [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/65938/how-to-publish-algorithm).

But I wanted to know if any one on SO would be willing / expected to review it (peer-review) and provide feedback.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Better ask such at [SE Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions) rather than Stack Overflow.
That site is specifically purposed for peer reviews of already working code.

Comment: This only works if OP has actual code and not just an algorithm.